# I can't update or install any software or packages in my ubuntu 11.10

Tags: software-center

The installation or removal of a software package failed.

```
installArchives() failed: perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%%
(Reading database ... 10%%
(Reading database ... 15%%
(Reading database ... 20%%
(Reading database ... 25%%
(Reading database ... 30%%
(Reading database ... 35%%
(Reading database ... 40%%
(Reading database ... 45%%
(Reading database ... 50%%
(Reading database ... 55%%
(Reading database ... 60%%
(Reading database ... 65%%
(Reading database ... 70%%
(Reading database ... 75%%
(Reading database ... 80%%
(Reading database ... 85%%
(Reading database ... 90%%
(Reading database ... 95%%
(Reading database ... 100%%
(Reading database ... 243832 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace isc-dhcp-client 4.1.1-P1-17ubuntu10.1 (using .../isc-dhcp-client_4.1.1-P1-17ubuntu10.3_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement isc-dhcp-client ...
Preparing to replace isc-dhcp-common 4.1.1-P1-17ubuntu10.1 (using .../isc-dhcp-common_4.1.1-P1-17ubuntu10.3_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement isc-dhcp-common ...
Preparing to replace bind9-host 1:9.7.3.dfsg-1ubuntu4.2 (using .../bind9-host_1%%3a9.7.3.dfsg-1ubuntu4.3_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement bind9-host ...
Preparing to replace dnsutils 1:9.7.3.dfsg-1ubuntu4.2 (using .../dnsutils_1%%3a9.7.3.dfsg-1ubuntu4.3_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement dnsutils ...
Preparing to replace libisc62 1:9.7.3.dfsg-1ubuntu4.2 (using .../libisc62_1%%3a9.7.3.dfsg-1ubuntu4.3_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libisc62 ...
Preparing to replace libdns69 1:9.7.3.dfsg-1ubuntu4.2 (using .../libdns69_1%%3a9.7.3.dfsg-1ubuntu4.3_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libdns69 ...
Preparing to replace libisccc60 1:9.7.3.dfsg-1ubuntu4.2 (using .../libisccc60_1%%3a9.7.3.dfsg-1ubuntu4.3_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libisccc60 ...
Preparing to replace libisccfg62 1:9.7.3.dfsg-1ubuntu4.2 (using .../libisccfg62_1%%3a9.7.3.dfsg-1ubuntu4.3_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libisccfg62 ...
Preparing to replace liblwres60 1:9.7.3.dfsg-1ubuntu4.2 (using .../liblwres60_1%%3a9.7.3.dfsg-1ubuntu4.3_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement liblwres60 ...
Preparing to replace libbind9-60 1:9.7.3.dfsg-1ubuntu4.2 (using .../libbind9-60_1%%3a9.7.3.dfsg-1ubuntu4.3_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libbind9-60 ...
Preparing to replace bind9utils 1:9.7.3.dfsg-1ubuntu4.2 (using .../bind9utils_1%%3a9.7.3.dfsg-1ubuntu4.3_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement bind9utils ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Setting up samba4 (4.0.0~alpha17~git20110807.dfsg1-1ubuntu1) ...
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Administrator password will be set randomly!
Unknown parameter encountered: "max log size"
Ignoring unknown parameter "max log size"
Unknown parameter encountered: "syslog"
Ignoring unknown parameter "syslog"
Unknown parameter encountered: "passdb backend"
Ignoring unknown parameter "passdb backend"
Unknown parameter encountered: "unix password sync"
Ignoring unknown parameter "unix password sync"
Unknown parameter encountered: "passwd program"
Ignoring unknown parameter "passwd program"
Unknown parameter encountered: "pam password change"
Ignoring unknown parameter "pam password change"
Unknown parameter encountered: "map to guest"
Ignoring unknown parameter "map to guest"
Unknown parameter encountered: "usershare allow guests"
Ignoring unknown parameter "usershare allow guests"
Unknown parameter encountered: "guest ok"
Ignoring unknown parameter "guest ok"
Unknown parameter encountered: "guest ok"
Ignoring unknown parameter "guest ok"
Unknown parameter encountered: "max log size"
Ignoring unknown parameter "max log size"
Unknown parameter encountered: "syslog"
Ignoring unknown parameter "syslog"
Unknown parameter encountered: "passdb backend"
Ignoring unknown parameter "passdb backend"
Unknown parameter encountered: "unix password sync"
Ignoring unknown parameter "unix password sync"
Unknown parameter encountered: "passwd program"
Ignoring unknown parameter "passwd program"
Unknown parameter encountered: "pam password change"
Ignoring unknown parameter "pam password change"
Unknown parameter encountered: "map to guest"
Ignoring unknown parameter "map to guest"
Unknown parameter encountered: "usershare allow guests"
Ignoring unknown parameter "usershare allow guests"
Unknown parameter encountered: "guest ok"
Ignoring unknown parameter "guest ok"
Unknown parameter encountered: "guest ok"
Ignoring unknown parameter "guest ok"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/samba/setup/provision", line 256, in <module>
    useeadb=eadb, next_rid=opts.next_rid, lp=lp)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 1602, in provision
    sitename=sitename)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 584, in guess_names
    raise InvalidNetbiosName(netbiosname)
samba.provision.InvalidNetbiosName: The name ''VIGNESHMOHA-VPCEA13EN'' is not a valid NetBIOS name
dpkg: error processing samba4 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Setting up isc-dhcp-common (4.1.1-P1-17ubuntu10.3) ...
Setting up isc-dhcp-client (4.1.1-P1-17ubuntu10.3) ...
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Setting up libisc62 (1:9.7.3.dfsg-1ubuntu4.3) ...
Setting up libdns69 (1:9.7.3.dfsg-1ubuntu4.3) ...
Setting up libisccc60 (1:9.7.3.dfsg-1ubuntu4.3) ...
Setting up libisccfg62 (1:9.7.3.dfsg-1ubuntu4.3) ...
Setting up libbind9-60 (1:9.7.3.dfsg-1ubuntu4.3) ...
Setting up liblwres60 (1:9.7.3.dfsg-1ubuntu4.3) ...
Setting up bind9-host (1:9.7.3.dfsg-1ubuntu4.3) ...
Setting up dnsutils (1:9.7.3.dfsg-1ubuntu4.3) ...
Setting up bind9utils (1:9.7.3.dfsg-1ubuntu4.3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Errors were encountered while processing:
 samba4
Setting up samba4 (4.0.0~alpha17~git20110807.dfsg1-1ubuntu1) ...
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Administrator password will be set randomly!
Unknown parameter encountered: "max log size"
Ignoring unknown parameter "max log size"
Unknown parameter encountered: "syslog"
Ignoring unknown parameter "syslog"
Unknown parameter encountered: "passdb backend"
Ignoring unknown parameter "passdb backend"
Unknown parameter encountered: "unix password sync"
Ignoring unknown parameter "unix password sync"
Unknown parameter encountered: "passwd program"
Ignoring unknown parameter "passwd program"
Unknown parameter encountered: "pam password change"
Ignoring unknown parameter "pam password change"
Unknown parameter encountered: "map to guest"
Ignoring unknown parameter "map to guest"
Unknown parameter encountered: "usershare allow guests"
Ignoring unknown parameter "usershare allow guests"
Unknown parameter encountered: "guest ok"
Ignoring unknown parameter "guest ok"
Unknown parameter encountered: "guest ok"
Ignoring unknown parameter "guest ok"
Unknown parameter encountered: "max log size"
Ignoring unknown parameter "max log size"
Unknown parameter encountered: "syslog"
Ignoring unknown parameter "syslog"
Unknown parameter encountered: "passdb backend"
Ignoring unknown parameter "passdb backend"
Unknown parameter encountered: "unix password sync"
Ignoring unknown parameter "unix password sync"
Unknown parameter encountered: "passwd program"
Ignoring unknown parameter "passwd program"
Unknown parameter encountered: "pam password change"
Ignoring unknown parameter "pam password change"
Unknown parameter encountered: "map to guest"
Ignoring unknown parameter "map to guest"
Unknown parameter encountered: "usershare allow guests"
Ignoring unknown parameter "usershare allow guests"
Unknown parameter encountered: "guest ok"
Ignoring unknown parameter "guest ok"
Unknown parameter encountered: "guest ok"
Ignoring unknown parameter "guest ok"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/samba/setup/provision", line 256, in <module>
    useeadb=eadb, next_rid=opts.next_rid, lp=lp)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 1602, in provision
    sitename=sitename)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 584, in guess_names
    raise InvalidNetbiosName(netbiosname)
samba.provision.InvalidNetbiosName: The name ''VIGNESHMOHA-VPCEA13EN'' is not a valid NetBIOS name
dpkg: error processing samba4 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! How are you trying to install? what was that package? Only providing an output is not very helpful. Try to provide more details. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed any .deb package before?

Because `dpkg -i` left some unstopped jobs.

Try to kill the processes which are using your installer.

Know them by typing `ps -e`.

And now try to install.

Comment: `ps -e` will also list plenty of processes that are not related to package management, and which should not be killed. I recommend editing this answer to provide more detailed information about how to identify which processes need to be terminated.